# Trigger Flutter code execution using APNS background silent notification in Swift

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm using APNS via Azure Notification Hub to send notifications to iOS devices, so I can't use FCM for background processing in Flutter, but I am trying to replicate something similar to FCM's `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myMessageHandler)` as described in their [manual](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages).

So, let's say I have the following push message:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

**I need to pass values `acme1` and `acme2` to Flutter, process them and exit.** 
According to [Apple doc's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app), to revive the app from `UIApplication.State.inactive` I need to add following override to my AppDelegate.swift:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        switch application.applicationState {
        case .inactive:
            
            // here I need to pass values to a handler
            // within Flutter framework

            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

And this is where I'm spinning my wheels.

For the cases when the app is in the foreground (UIApplication.State.active) or in the background but still active (UIApplication.State.background), I'n using `FlutterMethodChannel` to pass the data and that works great, but when the app was killed - I'm not sure what to do here. How do I start Flutter in headless mode, trigger a method and exit?